# How to get th:href="@{}" instead of href="" in links spring boot/angular app

Tags: html, angular, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two modules in one project, first module is frontend app `(Angular CLI 8)`, second backend Spring boot app. I'm trying to deploy both modules together using maven.

So I automatically copying dist folder from frontend app to backend resources.
In file generated by angular: `index.html` I have source to css files like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

but i need something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{styles.css}">
```

How to configure angular autogenerated in `dist` package what I want.

Comment: Do you really need thymeleaf to serve an angular application ?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I dont need thymeleaf, problem was in path to css/js files. These files should be default in resources/static/ package in backend module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build an front application with `Angular` and a backend with `Spring boot` I can only suggest you to take a loot at `Jhipster`.

> [Hipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) is a development platform to generate, develop and deploy Spring Boot + Angular / React / Vue Web applications and Spring microservices.

I use a lot JHipster to learn new stuffs like build, monitoring, deployment, security, best practices, etc.

They have done great things to make Angular get along with Spring Boot.

**Repository sample** : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

What you need to do is to set Angular configuration to set destination folder to `target/classes/static` then add configuration to spring boot for redirect to assets.